# Thinking Sphinx search for different conditions from the same join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

This question is similar to

[How do you search for different conditions from the same join table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573144/how-do-you-search-for-different-conditions-from-the-same-join-table), but I didn't get solution from this.z

My code

```
has_one    :insurance_type_link, as: :enumerable, class_name: "Utility::UserDefinedEnumLink",
         conditions: {user_defined_enum_links: {user_defined_enum_id: Utility::UserDefinedEnum.insurance_types.map(&:id)}}
has_one    :payment_duration_link, as: :enumerable, class_name: "Utility::UserDefinedEnumLink",
         conditions: {user_defined_enum_links: {user_defined_enum_id: Utility::UserDefinedEnum.payment_durations.map(&:id)}}
```

My define_index has this

```
indexes insurance_type_link.user_defined_enum.enum_value,  as: :it, sortable: :insensitive
indexes payment_duration_link.user_defined_enum.enum_value, as: :pd, sortable: :insensitive
```

And sql query generated inside  inside development.sphinx.conf is

```
AS `it_sort`, LOWER(IFNULL(`user_defined_enums_user_defined_enum_links`.`enum_value`, '')) 
AS `pd_sort`, IFNULL(`user_defined_enums`.`enum_value`, '')
```

So it is generating different query to both the relation as a result only first query is giving me proper search results.

How to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using a short cut method, not sure whether it is okay or not... I defined a third relation that include both the relations that I defined earlier only for the sake of searching 
and used that in define_index method .

Comment: If that does the job, I guess stick with it. I'd be curious as to what the joins in the sql_query value are without that shortcut, but really: you've got it working, focus on whatever's next :)

Comment: @Pat, I have mentioned the sql query value in my question (without the short cut). Thanks

Comment: You've only got the parts from the SELECT for those two fields - I was hoping to see the entire query.